# how to stream an HTML file as a download attachment with its resources

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, asp-classic, download

I would like to stream an HTML page to the client as a downloadable attachment.

I have set the content type to text/html and the content disposition to attachment.

I now face 2 issues:

1) The file encoding is not right. Hebrew chars ar distorted, although I did set the encoding to UTF-8.
2) The HTML resources are not in the download stream. I want to know if there is a claver way to add them...

Your thoughts...

Comment: It would help if you included some code, however if this is a classic asp issue I recommend reading this - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: @John I don't think it is.